# Issues loading fieldtrip data with MNE python

Tags: python, mne-python

I am having challenges loading fieldtrip data with MNE python. When I enter the code below

```
import mne
original_data = mne.io.read_raw_fif('data.fif', preload=False)
original_info = original_data.info
data_from_ft = mne.read_epochs_fieldtrip('data.mat', original_info)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0):

Is the Fieldtrip data in the form of epochs or raw? It is difficult to say without looking at the data, but you can try using mne.io.read_raw_fieldtrip() or read_evoked_fieldtrip() as the case may be.

It also helps to look at the [docs](https://mne.tools/stable/auto_tutorials/io/plot_10_reading_meg_data.html#fieldtrip-meg-eeg-data-mat) and ask on the more active [mailing list here](https://mail.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/mailman/listinfo/mne_analysis).